# How do I fix beveling edges?

Tags: modeling, bevel

When I try and bevel these edges, the curve always goes towards something and not just stay in it's same place.[image: the problem][image: Desired bevel]

Comment: Hi, R Stepper.. welcome to Blender SE. I think this one can be closed as a simple slip-up.. object-level scaling is a very common cause of questions here on BSE, so has been covered quite extensively. If you disagree, go ahead and edit with an explanation.Thanks. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's a simple slip up, covered extensively elsewhere, and self-answered.

Comment: @RobinBetts Just a question for my understanding: why was it closed as off-topic instead of being a duplicate? Because people who see this might be confused if the question about a Blender tool they are going to ask is off-topic as well although it's not...

Comment: Hi, @GordonBrinkmann the tools don't give us much scope, do they? The problem has arisen so many times i'm at a bit of a loss to choose which example to call a 'duplicate'. So this closure is Community > Other, partly because it was so quickly spotted and self-answered by OP. But the form-message still says 'Off-Topic'.. unfair. Do you want to pick a dupe, and we'll go again?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann .. cheers

Answer (score 0):

okay uhh i found out that i needed to put ctrl a in object mode and press scale before bevelling